# Scipy Optimize Curve_fit error for bounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, bounds

When I try to run:

```
bet = (nu[minimum],10**4,3000,0,0,5000)   # Array of initial bet parameters
bound = ( (nu[0],nu[len(nu)-1]),(10**3,10**6),(-np.inf,np.inf),(-np.inf,np.inf),(-np.inf,np.inf),(-np.inf,np.inf) )
popt,pcov = curve_fit(S_21,x,y, p0=bet, bounds = bound)
```

> TypeError: leastsq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bounds'

What is the problem? I use Python 3.4.4 on Windows.

Comment: The `bounds` argument was added in scipy version 0.17.  Which version are you using?  Check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scipy.optimize.leastsq` does not support bounds, and was used by `curve_fit` until scipy version 0.17.  OTOH, `scipy.optimize.least_squares` (which is used by `curve_fit` in more recent versions of scipy) can support bounds, but not when using the `lm` (Levenberg-Marquardt) method, because that is a simple wrapper around `scipy.optimize.leastsq`.   It is somewhat confusing.

Allow me to recommend trying `lmfit` (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) which does support bounds on all parameters, and makes it easy to fix/vary parameters without having to alter the model function. Lmfit has a convenient approach to curve fitting with its Model class, and a good number of tools for exploring the confidence intervals of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

another workaround that worked for me in versions of scipy below 0.17 (tried in 0.14 and 0.15) is to tell leastsq to do more calls to func (but this depends on the convergence speed of your func).

For example, you can try:

```
popt,pcov = curve_fit(S_21,x,y, p0=bet, maxfev=10000)
```